# Knockout Kendo TimePicker disable user text input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js, kendo-ui

How to disable user text input in Kendo UI TimePicker using knockout-kendo binding?

In my **non** knockout-kendo project I managed to do it using ([jsfiddle example here](http://jsfiddle.net/tstancin/uPeN6/3/)):

```
$('#timepicker').attr('disabled', 'disabled');  //disable user text input
```

That way the control dropdown is active, users can pick time values, but cannot type into the box, which is exactly what I want.

Now I'm working with knockout-kendo binding, and I can't find any option to disable user text input. ([jsfiddle knockout-kendo example here](http://jsfiddle.net/tstancin/uPeN6/2/)). Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use the 'enable' binding on the #timepicker:

```
<input id="timepicker" 
       data-bind="kendoTimePicker: { value: startTime, format: 'HH:mm' },
       enable: false" />
```

Demo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2UBjL/).

Comment: The enable binding is not supported by the TimePicker widget

Answer (score 1):

The binding supports an `enabled` option that you can bind against a boolean observable.

Something like:

```
<input data-bind="checked: isStartTimeEnabled" type="checkbox" />
<input id="timepicker" data-bind="kendoTimePicker: { value: startTime, format: 'HH:mm', enabled: isStartTimeEnabled }" />
```

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/R5NxJ/

Comment: when enabled is false, the whole control is disabled. I want the control to be enabled, but I don't want users to be able to type into the text-box

Comment: If you don't want the whole thing disabled, then the suggestion by @manji of using the `enable` binding would be sensible.